# How to change Google Chrome Arabic default font in css?

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, arabic, font-size

Arabic default font in Google Chrome is larger than it is in Firefox. How can I set the Chrome arabic font size to smaller in css or are there other possible solutions for this?

Comment: do some googling first before answer 

the first result 

http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95416

Comment: my friend, he says in CSS not in chrome browser

Comment: @Georges, i am afried you cant, usually browsers render some fonts differently than other browsers. you will find the same issue between Mac/Windows. if you want it very much u can use the User Agent to target specific browser

Comment: What do you mean by “Arabic default font”? As far as I can see, Chrome has default generic font, default serif font, default sans serif font, and default monospace font, but no separate default font settings for languages or scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .className {font-size: xx;} 
}
```

This is Media Query to target chrome

Comment: How does this target Chrome specifically, and how does it address the question about Arabic default font?

Comment: First, it works. Second, it has nothing to do specifically with Arabic it is in general to target the chrome browser

Comment: with PHP I detect if the language set by the user is Arabic, if yes add .chrome class to the element

Comment: @GeorgesKmeid, if this is the accepted answer, then your real question was very different from what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this plugin: Advanced Font Settings

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-font-settings/caclkomlalccbpcdllchkeecicepbmbm?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for ! Thank you. Arabic fonts aren't readable on most pages, it's frustrating ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to change these settings:

```
1.Click the Chrome menu  on the browser toolbar.
2.Select Settings.
3.Click Show advanced settings and go to the "Web Content" section.
4.Default fonts and encodings
```

then just change the size !